# Declare array of classes that conform to a protocol

Tags: swift

Lets say I have created this protocol and a couple of classes

```
import UIKit

protocol ControllerConstructorProtocol {
    class func construct() -> UIViewController?
}

class MyConstructor: ControllerConstructorProtocol {
    class func construct() -> UIViewController? {
        return UIViewController()
    }
}

class MyOtherConstructor: ControllerConstructorProtocol {
    class func construct() -> UIViewController? {
        return UITableViewController(style: .Grouped)
    }
}
```

Now I want to declare an array that contains classes of objects that will conform to such protocol.
How can I declare it? Ideally I would like the compiler to check the array is correctly filled (at compile time) rather than checking it myself at (run time) with the `as` operator.

This is what I have tried without success :(

1. This leads to a compile error:

   > 'Any Object does not have a member named 'construct'

   ```
   var array = [
       MyConstructor.self,
       MyOtherConstructor.self,
   ]

   var controller = array[0].construct() // << ERROR here
   ```
2. Writing this is even worse, since the class itself does not conform
   to the protocol (their instances do)

   > Type 'MyConstructor.Type' does not conform to protocol
   >   'ControllerConstructorProtocol'

   ```
   var array: Array<ControllerConstructorProtocol> = [
       MyConstructor.self, // << ERROR here
       MyOtherConstructor.self,
   ]
   ```

**EDIT 2016/04/23**: In Swift 2.2 (Xcode 7.3) it is possible to write [@rintaro's original idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28691376/149008) :)

```
let array: Array<ControllerConstructorProtocol.Type> = [
    MyConstructor.self,
    MyOtherConstructor.self,
]
let viewController = array[0].construct()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"array of classes that conform to a protocol" can be declared like `Array<TheProtocol.Type>`.

You can:

```
var array: Array<ControllerConstructorProtocol.Type> = [
    MyConstructor.self,
    MyOtherConstructor.self,
]
```

But...,

```
    array[0].construct()
//  ^ error: accessing members of protocol type value 'ControllerConstructorProtocol.Type' is unimplemented
```

Calling method on the item is "unimplemented".

As of now, you have to declare the protocol as `@objc`, and call the method via `AnyClass`. Moreover, for some reasons, we cannot directly cast `array[0]` to `AnyClass`, instead, we have to cast it to `Any`, then `AnyClass`.

```
@objc protocol ControllerConstructorProtocol {
    class func construct() -> UIViewController?
}

var array: Array<ControllerConstructorProtocol.Type> = [
    MyConstructor.self,
    MyOtherConstructor.self,
]

let vc = (array[0] as Any as AnyClass).construct()
```

Note: Casting problem was fixed in Swift 1.2 / Xcode 6.3. But "unimplemented" is "unimplmented" :(

---

Just random ideas:

It's depends on your actual use-case, but in this particular case, array of `()-> UIViewController?` closures is sufficient:

```
var array: [() -> UIViewController?] = [
    MyConstructor.construct,
    MyOtherConstructor.construct,
]

let vc = array[0]()
```

If you have several methods, you might want to use type-erased wrapper of the protocol.

```
protocol ControllerConstructorProtocol {
    class func construct() -> UIViewController?
    class func whoami() -> String
}

struct ControllerConstructorWrapper {
    private let _construct: () -> UIViewController?
    private let _whoami: () -> String
    init<T: ControllerConstructorProtocol>(_ t:T.Type) {
        _construct = { t.construct() }
        _whoami = { t.whoami() }
    }
    func construct() -> UIViewController? { return _construct() }
    func whoami() -> String { return _whoami() }
}

var array: [ControllerConstructorWrapper] = [
    ControllerConstructorWrapper(MyConstructor),
    ControllerConstructorWrapper(MyOtherConstructor),
]

let who = array[0].whoami()
let vc = array[0].construct()
```

Comment: I see. So "unimplemented" swift compiler developers are still on the work Am I correct. I guess at this time there is no solution without the `as` keyword.

Comment: Yes, I believe apple is working on it. I updated the answer, but I believe there is no straight forward way to handle this problem.

Comment: Now you mentioned it, having an array of closures is enough for me! ありがとうございました！

Comment: Great  answer rintaro.

Comment: Now this is possible: Declare `var array: [ControllerConstructorProtocol.Type] = [...]` and then `array[0].construct()` does not lead to compiler errors. I haven't tried with recent versions of Xcode6 but in Xcode7beta2 it is possible

Comment: @rintaro It is been a long time. I've been rethinking your answer about type-erased wrapper. And I have another question. Why hiding the type is necessary? I wish I could have an array: `var array: [ControllerConstructor< ControllerConstructorProtocol >] = [ControllerConstructor< MyViewController>(), ControllerConstructor< MyViewController2>() ]` and use it like: `var vc = array[0].construct()` however no matter how I define the protocol or the array I cannot get it to compile. Is this the reason you used type erased wrapper?

Comment: @nacho4d Because `ControllerConstructor<MyViewController>` and `ControllerConstructor<MyViewController2>` are two distinct types. Swift compiler have to determine the return type of `array[0].construct()`.

Comment: @rintaro In swift 2.2 it is possible to do your original idea. I have updated the answer saying that. Thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var myConst = MyConstructor()
var myOthConst = MyOtherConstructor()

var array:[AnyObject] = [
    myConst,
    myOthConst
]

for a in array
{
    if a is MyConstructor
    {
        println("a is type of MyConstructor")
        (a as! MyConstructor).myMethod()
    }
    else if a is MyOtherConstructor
    {
        println("a is type of MyOtherConstructor")
        (a as! MyOtherConstructor).myMethod()
    }
}
```

Another solution, although not that pretty...

Comment: I would prefer not to use `as something` as I wrote in the question. I wonder if there is a general way of doing this. Lets say I have 10 elements in the array ... I would have to write to many `as`es )

Comment: The problem is that the array is type of AnyObject, because there are multiple class types in the array, and the compiler doesnt know, which type is the element at index i. I'll update the answer with a better solution.

Comment: You are right, but those classes have the protocol in common. I would to declare an array of AnyClass but they should conform to ControllerConstructorProtocol, I don't even know is this is possible

Comment: should use array.first instead of array[0]. If you still using count - 1 keep in mind array.last

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got your question completely, but why not this way:

```
var array: [ControllerConstructorProtocol] = [MyConstructor(), MyOtherConstructor()]
```

Comment: He does not want to store instances but classes.

Comment: Instances are very expensive in my case. That is why I want the classes with a common method that will create the instances I need.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to sotre classes only (that conforms to protocol) then you can do it the following way (in Swift 3):

If you want to create a new instance with the protocol type you have to add init() to protocol declaration:

```
protocol SomeProtocol: ConformsToOtherProtocolIfNeeded {
    init(...) { ... }
    func someFunction(...) { ... }
}

class Class1: SomeProtocol {
    init(...) { ... }
    func someFunction(...) { ... }
}

class Class2: SomeProtocol {
    init(...) { ... }
    func someFunction(...) { ... }
}
```

declare array (as above):

```
var someProtocols: Array<SomeProtocol.Type> = [
    Class1.self,
    Class2.self,
]
```

and if you want to use someFunction, you have to create an instance, because the elements in the array not an instance.
Example:

```
for sp in someProtocols {
    let instance = sp.init()
    instance.someFunction()
}
```

If you want to compare the type of class, you also have to create an instance. (So you cannot use item of array directly (*sp*).)

Examples:

```
if type(of: instance) == type(of: otherInstance) { ... }
if instance is SomeProtocol { ... }
if instance is Class1 { ... }
```