# Accessing members of protocol type doesn't work in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

Following is the problem, that i cannot invoke class methods if the type is protocol.type. Is there an alternative pattern that could achieve this.

Real scenario is that i have arr: [SomeProtocol.Type] and i want to perform
let strings: [String] = arr.map { $0.str }

```
protocol SomeProtocol: class {
   static var str: String { get }

   static func value() -> Int
}

class SomeClass: SomeProtocol {
   static var str: String = "SomeClass"

   static func value() -> Int {
      return 1
   }
}

let protocolType: SomeProtocol.Type = SomeClass.self
println(protocolType.str) // compile error
println(protocolType.value()) // compile error
```

Comment: related: [Declare array of classes that conform to a protocol](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28691376/3804019)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

As you can see this part of swift is unimplemented. (Xcode 6.3 beta 4)