# Swift array of struct types conforming to protocol

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, struct

I have a series of several `struct`s conforming to `MyProtocol`. I need an array of these structs' *types* (because they have a static method declared in `MyProtocol` that I need to be able to access). I have tried all kinds of things but I can't make Xcode like it.

Also, before this is marked as dupe – I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28690399/declare-array-of-classes-that-conform-to-a-protocol), but all I got was:

```
//Foo and Bar are structs conforming to MyProtocol

let MyStructArray: Array<MyProtocol.self> = [Foo.self, Bar.self]
//Protocol 'MyProtocol' can only be used as a generic constant because it has Self or associated type requirements
```

Comment: Is `MyProtocol` a protocol that you wrote?  Why did you make the method static when you want to call it polymorphically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. My protocol was inheriting from `RawOptionSetType`. Not sure why that caused an issue, but commenting that inheritance out made it work. Weird.

Answer (score 9):

How about this?:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    static func hello()
}

struct Foo: MyProtocol {
    static func hello() {
        println("I am a Foo")
    }
    var a: Int
}

struct Bar: MyProtocol {
    static func hello() {
        println("I am a Bar")
    }
    var b: Double
}

struct Baz: MyProtocol {
    static func hello() {
        println("I am a Baz")
    }
    var b: Double
}

let mystructarray: Array<MyProtocol.Type> = [Foo.self, Bar.self, Baz.self]

(mystructarray[0] as? Foo.Type)?.hello()  // prints "I am a Foo"

for v in mystructarray {
    switch(v) {
    case let a as Foo.Type:
        a.hello()
    case let a as Bar.Type:
        a.hello()
    default:
        println("I am something else")
    }
}

// The above prints:
I am a Foo
I am a Bar
I am something else
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. If you don't use a type annotation as you did, the compiler cannot guess the type of the array, and I could not figure out what it wanted. So thanks so much for enlightening me.