# How to cast an typed array to one of the types protocols?

Tags: ios, swift

I have this in my playground:

```
func foo(printables: [Printable]) {
    // do something
}

enum MenuOptions: String, Printable {
    case ChangePickup = "Change Pickup Time"
    case RequestSupport = "Request Support"

    var description: String {
        get {
            return self.rawValue
        }
    }
}
var menuOptions: [MenuOptions] = [.ChangePickup]
foo(menuOptions)
let printables = menuOptions as [Printable]
```

Both last lines give a compiler error. I would expect `menuOptions` to be implicitly casted to `[Printable]` but the compiler complains with a `[MenuOptions] is not convertible to [Printable]` error. Am I missing something?

If I do `menuOptions as! AnyObject as! [Printable]` the compiler doesn't complain and the code works properly, but this seems dirty. Funnily enough, doing `foo(menuOptions.map { $0 })` also works! Is this just a compiler bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create a generic function constrained to objects that conform to the `Printable` protocol. Just define it differently:

```
func foo<T: Printable>(printables: [T]) {
    // do something
}
```

The function will now work in your context. It will take an array of any object type that conforms to `Printable`.

Here are the relevant docs on [Generics](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html), specifically [Type Constraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID186).

As to why this works, but your definition doesn't - this is just the Swift syntax. `Printable` is a protocol, but `T` is a type (generic, but still a type). You want your function to accept any type (`T`) that conforms to a protocol (`<T: Protocol>`). This is just how the language has been designed.

Using `menuOptions as! AnyObject as! [Printable]` may work in this example, but it is a bad practice. Using `as!` is like telling the compiler "trust me, this will work." This is fine in limited cases, but sets you up for trouble in the long run. Using `as!` turns off the compiler's type checking, which means if there is a problem it will happen at runtime, and your app will crash.

Again, I highly suggest reading the docs on Type Constraints, which I linked above. It explains it in detail.

Comment: This works, but do you know why the other options wouldn't?

Comment: @Matth I added a little more explanation; let me know if that helps!

Comment: This helps. I ran into this problem in a controller context. In my code I actually have a `var bar: [Printable] = []`  and a `foo(printables: [Printable])` in my UIViewController that sets its value. Making foo generic and setting the value also fails with the same kind of errors. And I can't make the whole controller generic (see stackoverflow.com/q/26097581/3804019). Is there just no way out of this?

Comment: The crux of the issue here is that you are trying to use `Printable` like a _type_, but it is not a type - it's a _protocol_. Really you should try to fix that mismatch. A little searching lead me to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28691376/2194039). Basically, there is no good way to do what you want, so one workaround suggested is to wrap this functionality in a generic `struct` that is constrained on `Printable`. But again, I think you should try to rethink what you are doing, because it seems a bit hacky.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this is working. It seems that Swift compiler is not that smart.

```
var menuOptions: [MenuOptions] = [MenuOptions.ChangePickup]
let printables:[Printable] =  menuOptions as! [Printable]
foo(printables)
```

I don't know why these are not working

```
foo(menuOptions)
foo(menuOptions as! [Printable])
```

Comment: I copied your code and I still get an error in the seconds line: 'Printable' is not a subtype of 'MenuOptions'. You don't get that error? What version of swift/xcode are you on?

Comment: I don't know how to get my swift version. How can I do that?